# How to convert a particular dataframe into a series by combining columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

Given the following data, where `3` means `yes` and `2` means `no`

```py
t = pd.DataFrame({"v_1": [2, 2, 3], "v_2": [2, 3, 2], "v_3": [3, 2, 2],})
```

which looks as

```
   v_1  v_2  v_3
0    2    2    3
1    2    3    2
2    3    2    2
```

I would like to create the following series

```
0    v_3
1    v_2
2    v_1
```

All I cna think of is the following:

```py
t['V'] = t.sum().reset_index(drop=True)
```

which gives

```py
   v_1  v_2  v_3    V
0            v_3  v_1
1       v_2       v_2
2  v_1            v_3
```

I'm wondering if there's a nicer approach than this, or perhaps more general.

Comment: u just want a series of the columns?

Comment: @sammywemmy essentially - each column currently represents a level, so it's basically one-hot encoded. And I want to be able to convert that to a single column instead of spreading out across many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for replace non `3` values to missing values, then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), remove first level of `MultiIndex` and last create `Series` from `index` if performance is important:

```
s = pd.Series(t.where(t.eq(3)).stack().droplevel(0).index)
#alternative
#s = pd.Series(t.where(t.eq(3)).stack().reset_index(0, drop=True).index)
print (s)
0    v_3
1    v_2
2    v_1
dtype: object
```

**Details**:

```
print (t.where(t.eq(3)))
   v_1  v_2  v_3
0  NaN  NaN  3.0
1  NaN  3.0  NaN
2  3.0  NaN  NaN
print (t.where(t.eq(3)).stack())
0  v_3    3.0
1  v_2    3.0
2  v_1    3.0
dtype: float64
print (t.where(t.eq(3)).stack().droplevel(0))
v_3    3.0
v_2    3.0
v_1    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Performance for 1k rows and 10 columns:

```
np.random.seed(123)

t = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([2,3], (1000, 10))).add_prefix('v_')
#print (t)

In [25]: %timeit pd.Series(t.where(t.eq(3)).stack().droplevel(0).index)
2.66 ms ± 93.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit pd.Series(t.where(t.eq(3)).stack().reset_index(0, drop=True).index)
2.61 ms ± 41.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
In [27]: %timeit t.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.eq(3), x.name, None)).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
5.98 ms ± 46.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [28]: %timeit t.stack().droplevel(0).loc[lambda x: x.eq(3)].reset_index(name='temp').drop('temp',axis=1)
3.48 ms ± 36.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

Performance for 100k rows and 10 columns:

```
t = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([2,3], (100000, 10))).add_prefix('v_')
print (t)
In [30]: %timeit pd.Series(t.where(t.eq(3)).stack().droplevel(0).index)
84.7 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [31]: %timeit pd.Series(t.where(t.eq(3)).stack().reset_index(0, drop=True).index)
84.1 ms ± 459 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
In [32]: %timeit t.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.eq(3), x.name, None)).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
147 ms ± 688 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [33]: %timeit t.stack().droplevel(0).loc[lambda x: x.eq(3)].reset_index(name='temp').drop('temp',axis=1)
101 ms ± 635 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you need, to keep the 3s and concat them in a series?

```
(
    t.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.eq(3), x.name, None))
    .stack().reset_index(drop=True)
)

0    v_3
1    v_2
2    v_1
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a whirl :

```
(t
 .stack()
 .droplevel(0)
 .loc[lambda x: x.eq(3)]
 .reset_index(name='temp')
 .drop('temp',axis=1)
 )

    index
0   v_3
1   v_2
2   v_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new index that has the location of 3 for each column. Then you apply that index to your column names.

```
import pandas as pd
t = pd.DataFrame({"v_1": [2, 2, 3], "v_2": [2, 3, 2], "v_3": [3, 2, 2],})

index_list = [t[t[col]==3].index[0] for col in t.columns] # create new index
series = pd.Series(t.columns) # series of column names
series.index = index_list # apply index to column names
print(series.sort_index())
```

Comment: I dont add solution to my timings because not working correct if duplicated `3` value per columns.